# Can I use a recursive CTE to find the min date across a "thread" of IDs?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables, ActiveContacts and CompletedContacts. ActiveContacts contains contacts that have not been closed, but may have spawned from a contact in CompletedContacts.

I need to find the minimum ContactStart for all Contacts in ActiveContacts, all the way through to the first related contact in CompletedContacts, if any exist. You know you have reached the "root" when the ContactID = MasterContactID.

For example, in my sample data:

```
From ActiveContacts
45227565918 --> 45130250258
From CompletedContacts
45130250258 --> 45065182801
45065182801 --> 45065111275
45065111275 --> 44987017334
44987017334 --> 44986804829
44986804829 --> 44986804829 --> 2019-02-25 07:48:00.00
```

In some cases, the ContactID will only exist on ActiveContact because it was not spawned from another contacts on CompletedContacts.

```
45562514264 --> 45562514264 --> 2019-03-27 02:44:00.000
```

I am thinking that this may be achievable via a recursive CTE, but I cannot get it right.  Is this possible?  My only other idea is a row by row cursor type situation.

Sample code below.

```
CREATE TABLE CustServ.WF.ActiveContactsTest
(
ContactID [bigint],
MasterContactID [bigint],
ContactStart [datetime]
);

INSERT INTO CustServ.WF.ActiveContactsTest (ContactID, MasterContactID, ContactStart)
VALUES
(45227565918,45130250258,'3/8/19 17:29'),
(45547409273,45545833249,'3/26/19 19:44'),
(45547477525,45547474793,'3/26/19 22:45'),
(45547491195,45547491195,'3/26/19 23:27'),
(45562514264,45562514264,'3/27/19 2:44');


CREATE TABLE CustServ.WF.CompletedContactsTest
(
ContactID [bigint],
MasterContactID [bigint],
ContactStart [datetime]
);

INSERT INTO CustServ.WF.CompletedContactsTest (ContactID, MasterContactID, ContactStart)
VALUES
(45130250258,45065182801,'3/4/19 17:22'),   -- From 1st row in ActiveContacts
(45065182801,45065111275,'2/28/19 14:11'),
(45065111275,44987017334,'2/28/19 13:49'),
(44987017334,44986804829,'2/25/19 9:20'),
(44986804829,44986804829,'2/25/19 7:48'),

(45545833249,45510675166,'3/26/19 9:44'),   -- From 2nd row in ActiveContacts
(45510675166,44056741709,'3/25/19 9:35'),
(44056741709,45435906188,'3/21/19 18:50'),
(45435906188,45370464489,'3/20/19 17:15'),
(45370464489,45318017172,'3/18/19 15:31'),
(45318017172,45280077660,'3/14/19 13:16'),
(45280077660,45280077660,'3/12/19 13:24'),

(45547474793,45547474793,'3/26/19 22:31');  -- From 3rd row in ActiveContacts
```

Comment: Just for future reference, you could make your question easier to follow and draw more attention using sample data like 1, 2, 3 instead of 11-digit numbers.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve then update your question with simplified sample data that demonstrates the behaviour you want.

Comment: Start with a recursive CTE that follows the hierarchy, then add a column that uses a `case` expression to either return the current row's date or the existing minimum date, whichever is smaller. You can also add a column to track which contact supplied the minimum value (assuming no ties).

Answer (score 0):

This is a mess of a data model, having links represented in two tables.  But you can do this:

```
with t as (
      select contactID, MasterContactID, ContactStart, 0 as isactive
      from CompletedContactsTest
      -- where contactID = MasterContactID
      union all
      select contactID, MasterContactID, ContactStart, 1 as isactive
      from ActiveContactsTest
      -- where contactID = MasterContactID
     ),
     cte as (
      select contactID, MasterContactID, ContactStart, 1 as lev, isactive
      from t
      where contactID = MasterContactID
      union all
      select t.contactID, cte.MasterContactID, cte.ContactStart, lev + 1, t.isactive
      from t join
           cte
           on t.contactID = cte.MasterContactID
      where t.contactID <> t.MasterContactID
     )
select contactid, min(contactstart)
from cte
where isactive = 1
group by contactid;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c3a3378e38d418973977b61a34cc29ca) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: That only appears to return the contacts that only had relationships in the ActiveContacts table. i.e ContactID = MasterContactID

Comment: @user786028 . . . Remove the `where` condition in the outer query to see if that gets you what you want.